# Vectorizing numpy code

Tags: numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to vectorize the following code -

```
for i in range(imL.shape[0]):
    for j in range(imL.shape[1]):
        if j - disp[i][j] >= 0:
            imR[i, j - disp[i][j], :] = imL[i, j, :]
```

Essentially, I want to do this -

```
A[i, j - B[i, j], k] = C[i, j, k] for all (i, j, k)
```

I looked into boolean indexing and came up with this -

```
tmp = np.arange(imR.shape[1])
tmp = np.repeat(tmp[np.newaxis, :], imR.shape[0], axis=0)
tmp = np.repeat(tmp[:, :, np.newaxis], imR.shape[2], axis=2)

imR[(tmp - disp) >= 0] = imL
```

However, this throws up the error -

```
TypeError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 3 dimensions
```

I believe integer indexing is the solution, however, I am unable to come up with anything. Is there a way to vectorize this efficiently?

NOTE: imL and imR are N x M x 3 ndarrays. disp is an N x M ndarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the creation of a temporary indices array with [np.indices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html):

```
i_indices, j_indices = np.indices(disp.shape)
```

Then you can create an updated index array with your custom formula:

```
# j - B[i, k]
new_j_ind = j_indices - disp
```

Replace the updated `j` values with the original `j`s on the condition:

```
# if j - disp[i][j] < 0, keep original j index
new_j_ind[new_j_ind < 0] = j_indices[new_j_ind < 0]
```

And write the array.

```
# A[i, j - B[i, j] if j - B[i, j] > 0 else j, k] = C[i, j, k] for all (i, j, k)
imR[i_indices, new_j_ind] = imL
```

Careful though: this is not well defined if `[i, j - B[i, j]]` ever map to the same coordinates for any (i, k). In the for loop it's well defined (the last written value wins), in the numpy vectorization code it is not.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding using `np.indices` for the temporary indices array. However, the step `imR[select] = imL[select]` is not semantically what I want to achieve. I believe it translates to `A[i, j - B[i, j], k] = C[i, j - B[i, j], k] for all (i, j, k)`. It definitely does not give me the same result as compared to a for-loop.

Comment: Indeed, I misread the question. The solution originally presented was `A[i, j, k] = C[i, j, k] for all (i, j, k) where j - B[i, j] > 0`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I did not understand how the indexing worked in `imR[i_indices, new_j_ind] = imL`. Could you point me to some resource where I might understand it further?

Comment: The documentation has a couple of good examples, you can start there: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing. I often find it helpful to take a simple example (like the one from the doc) and play around with it in an iPython session.